# How to simulate $resource angularjs using chrome postman app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I am trying to simulate this code

```
 var searchResource = $resource(
        apiUrl+'messages/search/','',
        {
        'queryAll':{method:'POST',isArray:true},
        'search':{method:'POST',isArray:true, headers:{'Authorization':token}},
        'query':{method:'POST',isArray:true, headers:{'Authorization':token}},
        'update':{method:'PUT',isArray:true, headers:{'Authorization':token}}
        }
        );
```

using POSTMAN restclient from google chrome browser.  How do I do this?
I have the authorization token and the rest of the api url